# How to loop rails variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have totally nine buttons in rails. I have input the data into the database by manually typing the `@button_1.save` function.

**My question is:**

How can i have the @button_i.save function in rails? I have finished the things in the for loop, what is left is the button save functions.

Many thanks!

```
      button_number = params[:button_number]

      for i in (1..button_number)
         instance_variable_set("@button#{i}", 
                               Button.new(:title => params["button_title_#{i}".to_sym], 
                               :order => i, 
                               :icon_url => params["button_icon_#{i}".to_sym], 
                               :navigation_id => @navigation.id, 
                               :next_navigation => params["selected_navigation_#{i}".to_sym].to_i, 
                               :next_page => params["selected_page_#{i}".to_sym].to_i))
         instance_variable_set("@button#{i}")
      end

      @button1.save
      @button2.save
      @button3.save
      @button4.save
      @button5.save
      @button6.save
```

Comment: may you post your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in ...
  eval("@button#{i}.save")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of `instance_variable_set` is `instance_variable_get`, which I think will lead you to the correct answer:

```
1.upto(params[:button_number].to_i) do |i|
  instance_variable_set("@button#{i}", 
    Button.new(
      :title => params["button_title_#{i}".to_sym], 
      :order => i, 
      :icon_url => params["button_icon_#{i}".to_sym], 
      :navigation_id => @navigation.id, 
      :next_navigation => params["selected_navigation_#{i}".to_sym].to_i, 
      :next_page => params["selected_page_#{i}".to_sym].to_i
    )
  )
  instance_variable_get("@button#{i}").save
end
```

Comment: i add .to_i to the params and make it correct. thanks! params[:button_number].to_i

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `constantize` ruby function because I think your function call statement is in string.

```
button_number = params[:button_number]

      for i in (1..button_number)
         instance_variable_set("@button#{i}", 
                               Button.new(:title => params["button_title_#{i}".to_sym], 
                               :order => i, 
                               :icon_url => params["button_icon_#{i}".to_sym], 
                               :navigation_id => @navigation.id, 
                               :next_navigation => params["selected_navigation_#{i}".to_sym].to_i, 
                               :next_page => params["selected_page_#{i}".to_sym].to_i))
        "@button#{i}".constantize.save();
      end
```

Comment: how to use the constantize function?

Comment: you can use constanize function in function call statement

Answer (score -1):

May be this that you want -

```
button_number = params[:button_number].to_i

for i in (1..button_number)
             instance_variable_set("@button#{i}", 
                                   Button.new(:title => params["button_title_#{i}".to_sym], 
                                   :order => i, 
                                   :icon_url => params["button_icon_#{i}".to_sym], 
                                   :navigation_id => @navigation.id, 
                                   :next_navigation => params["selected_navigation_#{i}".to_sym].to_i, 
                                   :next_page => params["selected_page_#{i}".to_sym].to_i))
             instance_variable_set("@button#{i}")

      "@button#{i}".save

      end
```

Comment: thanks man, but it shows "bad value for range", how to deal with it?

Comment: this is because the `params[:button_number]` that you are getting is an object and not a number. Please check my updated post above.

Comment: good to know that the solution worked. :) but did eval solved it too as you accepted that as a answer and in below post you commented that .to_i to the params made it correct.?

Comment: ya, the problem is the .to_i affect the most